# The date () function returns previous date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, sql-update

i used a simple script to update the current date at the server side through crone job but it returns previous date. The windows date is correct. i tried to check the script in online php editor and it return previous date. don't know where is the problem.

```
<?php
$current_date = date("Y/m/d");

$update_d = "UPDATE product SET c_date = '$current_date' ";
$run_d = mysqli_query($con, $update_d);

if ($run_d) {    
    echo "<script>alert('Current Date Updated Successfully!')</script>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Where do you set variable `$current_date`?

Comment: i set it $current_date = date("Y/m/d"):   this script is attached with crone job to update it on daily basis.so that data manipulate between tables...

Comment: You realize that you're updating your entire database; is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

Why not do the whole operation in the database rather than passing a variable from your code? In MySQL, `current_date` gives you the current date (without the time component), so:

```
$update_d = "UPDATE product SET c_date = current_date";
$run_d = mysqli_query($update_d);
```

Comment: how to do it in mysql? sorry i am new to php and this forum..

Comment: @MuhammadArif: this is what I showed in my answer. You can just replace the corresponding lines in your code with these two lines.

Comment: don't get your point, how will this work with database connection..how to write it in the database...

Comment: This didn't work because of the missing connection for  `mysqli_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following mysql code

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y/%m/%d');
```

Gives you as result *2020/04/30*

So following code would do what you want

```
<?php

$update_d = "UPDATE product SET c_date = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y/%m/%d');";
$run_d = mysqli_query($con, $update_d);

if ($run_d) {    
    echo "<script>alert('Current Date Updated Successfully!')</script>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting? -what kind of field is c_date  ithought it was varchar bbecause you wrote $current_date = date("Y/m/d"); and that is no vaild date format in mysql